# Laravel Homestead NPM Install Gulp no go

Tags: node.js, laravel, vagrant

I've updated NPM to the latest on Laravel's Homestead template for Vagrant. I wanted to install Gulp in one of my directories, but upon running "npm install" a directory with package.json I got this:

```
npm ERR! UNKNOWN, mkdir '/home/vagrant/Code/gulp/node_modules/gulp-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-optipng/node_modules/optipng-bin/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/bin-version-check/node_modules/bin-version/node_modules/find-versions'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-30-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm  v2.1.5
npm ERR! path /home/vagrant/Code/gulp/node_modules/gulpimagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-jpegtran/node_modules/jpegtranbin/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/bin-version-check/node_modules/bin-version/node_modules/find-versions
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! errno -1
```

Thousands of those messages. I'm working in Windows 7, Virtual Box.

Comment: Looks like something went wrong with the install. Uninstall Node and try again?

Answer (score 0):

You're running into windows max path length. Try installing gulp globally `npm install --global gulp`

Answer (score 0):

For an actual solution to this, check out [this comment](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7228#issuecomment-82829637), or continue reading here:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["sharedfolder", "add", :id, "--name", "www", "--hostpath", (("//?/" + File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/www").gsub("/","\\"))]
end

config.vm.provision :shell, inline: "mkdir /home/vagrant/www"
config.vm.provision :shell, inline: "mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`getent group vagrant | cut -d: -f3` www /home/vagrant/www", run: "always"
```

In the code above, I am appending \\?\ to the current directory absolute path. This will actually force the Windows API to allow an increase in the MAX_PATH variable (normally capped at 260). Read more about [max path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath). This is happening during the sharedfolder creation which is intentionally handled by VBoxManage and not Vagrant's "synced_folder" method. The last bit is pretty self-explanatory; we create the new shared folder and then make sure it's mounted each time the machine is accessed or touched since Vagrant likes to reload its mounts/shared folders on each load.

I hope this helps!